# How do I fake a validation error?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, grails-domain-class

I'm using the [Grails Webflow](http://www.grails.org/WebFlow) plugin.  Here are the domain objects I'm working with:

```
class Foo implements Serializable {
    String fooProp1,
           fooProp2

    static constraints = {
        fooProp2 nullable: false
    }
}

class Bar implements Serializable {
    Foo fooObject

    static constraints = {
        fooObject nullable: false
    }
}
```

At a point in the webflow, I need to make sure that fooObject.fooProp1 is not null.  If it is, I want to throw an error and force the user to supply it with a value.  I tried using validate() to do this (on both the Bar and Foo objects), but since fooProp1 has the nullable:true property, it passes validation.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - if this is the case, shouldn't the property just be `nullable: false`? Can you clarify why you can't add the constraint to your domain? That's the most obvious solution to me, I guess.

Comment: Well, the Foo objects are allowed to exist in the database without a fooProp1 specified.  However, during the webflow, this property needs to not be null, as it is used at the end of the webflow process.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can probably do this in the Web Flow by adapting the following code:

```
if(fooObject.fooProp1 == null) {
    fooObject.errors.rejectValue('fooProp1', 'nullable')
}
```

The second argument to that method, `'nullable'`, might be different for your situation. You'll just need to set it to the message code (from message.properties) to display the error message that you want.

Have a look [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/errors.html) for more ways to use `reject()` and `rejectValue()`.